# how to add new li to ul and removing the older ones

Tags: javascript

I need to take the user input and append it into the list element and remove one of the older list items with each new list item input.

```js
const addToDoBtn = getElementById('btn-addTodo');

const changeAddToDoF = () => {

  var ul = document.getElementById('todoList').removeAttribute;
  var todoInput = document.getElementById('todoInput').value,
    listNode = document.getElementById('todoList'),
    liNode = document.createElement('LI'),
    textNode = document.createTextNode(todoInput);

  liNode.appendChild(textNode);
  listNode.appendChild(liNode);
}
addToDoBtn.addEventListener("click", () => changeAddToDoF());
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>Todos:</h3>
  <ul id="todoList">
    <li>Hack the future</li>
    <li>Learn javascript</li>
    <li>Take over the world</li>
  </ul>
  <input type="text" id="todoInput" />
  <button id="btn-addTodo">Add todo</button>
</div>
```

but nothing happen at all

Comment: Two problems. First, your supposed reference to the UL is actually a reference to its `removeAttribute` method. Secondly, you don't ever append the LI to the UL.

Comment: Run your code (or open your console). It breaks at line 1 : `Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementById is not defined`. This is why nothing is happening.

Comment: can you elaborate more please.

Comment: It should be `document.getElementById`. This would fix line 1. Then your code works. Your console is telling you what's wrong

Comment: it was a typo i fixed it but still no resultes

Comment: Yes, there are actually many errors. I posted an answer with a working snippet

Answer (score 1):

This solution removes the oldest todo and appends new to-do to the bottom of the list. I've modified your solution accordingly.

Hope this is helpful.

```js
(function() {
   const addToDoBtn = document.getElementById('btn-addTodo');

const changeAddToDoF = () => {
  var todoInput = document.getElementById('todoInput').value,
  listNode = document.getElementById('todoList'),
  liNode = document.createElement('li'),
  textNode = document.createTextNode(todoInput);
  liNode.appendChild(textNode);
  
  //Removes old item from the list
  listNode.removeChild(listNode.getElementsByTagName('li')[0]);
  // appends the new item to the list
  listNode.appendChild(liNode);
}

addToDoBtn.addEventListener("click", () => changeAddToDoF());
})();
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>Todos:</h3>
  <ul id="todoList">
    <li>Hack the future</li>
    <li>Learn javascript</li>
    <li>Take over the world</li>
  </ul>
  <input type="text" id="todoInput" />
  <button id="btn-addTodo">Add todo</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would adding something to do automatically remove the oldest entry?

Comment: That's what his requirement is as per the question: `I need to take the user input and append it into the list element and remove one of the older list items with each new list item input.`, did I understand it wrong? I'll modify the solution if needed.

Comment: ah, no, I skipped this part. Sorry :) You're right. It just seems an odd requirement that the todo list can't grow.

Comment: it is very help full. it worked perfectly. to be honest I wrote some lines from other snippets on the internet without understanding them. for instance why the variables listNode ,liNode or textNode are not declared with var, const or let. I am still at the very beginning of learning JS. thanx a lot

Comment: Cool :) Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. And here is an impressive article about var, let and const: https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75

Answer (score 0):

Open your console (F12 in Chrome). It tells you what the problem is : `Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementById is not defined`. It should be `document.getElementById` like everywhere else in your code. Line 1 fixed, then here are some code optimisation suggestions (cache DOM elements) and bugfixes :

```js
const addToDoBtn = document.getElementById('btn-addTodo'),
      ul = document.getElementById('todoList'),
      todoInput = document.getElementById('todoInput');
      
      

const changeAddToDoF = () => {

  const liNode = document.createElement('li'),
    textNode = document.createTextNode(todoInput.value);

  liNode.appendChild(textNode);
  ul.appendChild(liNode);
  
  todoInput.value= "";
}

addToDoBtn.addEventListener("click", changeAddToDoF);
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>Todos:</h3>
  <ul id="todoList">
    <li>Hack the future</li>
    <li>Learn javascript</li>
    <li>Take over the world</li>
  </ul>
  <input type="text" id="todoInput" />
  <button id="btn-addTodo">Add todo</button>
</div>
```